# The data passed via this.props.history.push has weird behavior in the target page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to push from base component to another with some data defined in the base component which is sent as params with `history.push`.

**`Base Component`**

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component
{
    gotoTargetPage()
    {
      const params = { data: {fname: 'john', lname: 'doe' } };
      this.props.history.push('/target-page', params);
    }

    render()
    {
      return( <button onClick={event => this.gotoTargetPage()}>Go!</button>)
    }
}

export default withRouter(BaseComponent);
```

**`TargetPage Component:`**

```
class TargetComponent extends React.Component
{
    componentDidMount()
    {
      console.log(this.props.history.location.state.data);
    }

    render()
    {
      return( <div>Hi! I am {this.props.history.location.state.data.fname}.</div>)
    }
}
```

When I click the button on the base component, it successfully loads the target page. But console logs `this.props.history.state` as `undefined` and it renders data without the params (since it's not available).

Here's the twist. If I refresh the page, I can see the data being displayed and  console correctly logs the data. Not just if I refresh but If I hit the back button (after the first step), the data is displayed and console logs the data. Also, this happens approximately 75% of the time, and in about one in four tries, it happens without any problem.

I repeated the same situation creating new component but with the same result. What could be the reason for this?

**`Environment:`**

```
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-router": "^4.1.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be combining two signatures of `history.push()` (See https://github.com/reacttraining/history)

Either you pass a path URL and an optional state object

```
history.push('/some/path', { some: 'state' })
```

Or you pass everything in a single object

```
history.push({ 
    pathname: '/home',
    state: { some: 'state' }
})
```

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. I had accidentally misplaced the curly braces while trying to reproduce the question. I tried both of these options, but with exactly the same result.

Comment: is TargetComponent rendered via a `<Route>`?

Comment: Yes. Like so: `<Route exact path='target-page' component={TargetComponent} />`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the component was re-rendering again for some other reason then the props would lose the params sent, thus setting `this.props.history.location = undefined`. The following approach worked for me.

```
/**
 * When component mounts, grab the params if there is any and setState
 */
componentWillMount()
{
    // when params sent via url
    if (this.props.history.location.state)
    {
        let params = this.props.history.location.state;
        this.setState({ params });
    }
}
```

Since the data is now stored in the component state, it isn't lost and is available everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access data in class component passed through history.push()

Instead of:

```
 {this.props.history.location.state.data.fname}
```

Use

```
 {this.props.history.location.state.fname}
```